# What are the differences between the various partition tables?

Tags: partition, partition-table

When I am looking to create a new partition table, I have the following options:

- `aix`
- `amiga`
- `bsd`
- `dvh`
- `gpt`
- `mac`
- `msdos`
- `pc98`
- `sun`
- `loop`

The default in gparted appears to be `msdos` which I guess is an 'MBR' partition table. However `gpt` is more recent, but has less Windows support. I've used Linux for a long time, but I've never really looked into partitioning.

What are the various options and their differences? Is there a recommended one for Linux-only disks?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The options correspond to the various partitioning systems supported in [`libparted`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/); there's not [much documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mklabel.html#mklabel), but looking at [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parted.git/tree/libparted/labels):

- `aix` provides support for the volumes used in IBM’s AIX (which introduced what we now know as LVM);
- `amiga` provides support for the Amiga’s RDB partitioning scheme;
- `bsd` provides support for BSD disk labels;
- `dvh` provides support for SGI disk volume headers;
- `gpt` provides support for GUID partition tables;
- `mac` provides support for old (pre-GPT) Apple partition tables;
- `msdos` provides support for DOS-style MBR partition tables;
- `pc98` provides support for [PC-98](http://people.freebsd.org/~kato/pc98.html) partition tables;
- `sun` provides support for Sun’s partitioning scheme;
- `loop` provides support for raw disk access (loopback-style) — I’m not sure about the uses for this one.

As you can see, the majority of these are for older systems, and you probably won’t need to create a partition table of any type other than `gpt` or `msdos`.

For a new disk, **I recommend `gpt`**: it allows more partitions, it can be booted even in pre-UEFI systems (using `grub`), and supports disks larger than 2 TiB (up to 8 ZiB for 512-byte sector disks). Actually, if you don’t need to boot from the disk, I’d recommend not using a partitioning scheme at all and simply adding the whole disk to `mdadm`, LVM, or a zpool, depending on whether you use LVM (on top of `mdadm` or not) or ZFS.

Comment: +1. If you add an entire disk to a zfsonlinux pool, it will create two gpt partitions, an ashift-aligned partition 1 with the bulk of the disk, and a small partition 9 at the end of the disk for the [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition).  As with MBR, there is enough space before the start of partition 1 for a boot-loader like grub.

Comment: Could you explain more in detail, why you "recommend not using a partitioning scheme" if the drive is not required for booting? Why is it better to have no partition table at all?

Comment: Additional information about NOT creating a partition can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/q/439022/156108) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76593/195117).  From what I can tell this is not a good idea and doesn't outweigh the benefit of having a partition just so other utilities and systems will recognize the disk "has something on it" rather than just looking totally empty.

Comment: Using `loop` "partition table" destroys any partition table. It's useful when you want to get rid of a `gpt` table, as a `gpt` has 2 tables, the primary, at the first sectors of your drive, and the secondary (backup) table, at the last sectors of your drive.

Comment: @StephenKitt "loop" essentially means that you do not have a paertition table et al, instead you format and mount the whole block device. Very, very useful if you do not want to s..k with things just mount them, particularly in virtualized environments, too.

Answer (score 16):

Yes `msdos` is the Master Boot Record based partioning.

You should either go with `msdos` or with `gpt`. You will have to go with gpt if you want more than 7 partitions (unless you want a non-standard MBR, which I don't recommend, you never know what utilities assume the msdos/windows restrictions). You also have to go with `gpt` if you have drives > 2Tb.

If this is a Linux only disc that will never go into a really old Linux system not supporting `gpt`, then going with `gpt` is the easiest.

Comment: The old MBR partitioning scheme supports an indefinite length chain of "logical drives" (i.e. secondary partitions) within the "extended partition". This limit of 7 that you state does not come from the partitioning scheme itself, nor indeed (to my knowledge) from any operating systems that handle it. I've had assigned drive letters going a good two thirds of the way to the end of the alphabet in years gone past. The EFI partitioning scheme is definitely the superior choice nowadays, though, in part because all of the befuddlement and folklore about primary and extended partitions goes away.