# add additional msdos based partition using maximal amount of space

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gpt, parted

Stumbled about a problem with gpt:

```
[root@someserver ~]#   parted /dev/sdb
GNU Parted 2.1
Using /dev/sdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8619GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  2022GB  2022GB  primary               lvm
```

I would need to create (one or more) additional partitions using msdos format.
As far as I know msdos can only store up to 2 TB per partition.

How can I add additional partitions using the maximal amount per msdos partition?
Would a simple call to `mkpart logical 0% 100%` be enough?

Comment: GPT is not a partition type but a **partition table** type. Do you want to convert the partition table? see https://serverfault.com/q/963178

Comment: @Bodo no. I just want to create a new partition under `dev/sdb` using `gpt` as partition table type. This new partition should use GPT so I can use the additional space (2023GB-8619GB) as size for this additional partition.

Comment: You can only have **either** a partition table of type `msdos` **or** a partition table of type `gpt`, so if you want to add "a GPT partition"  you have to convert the partition table. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289389/330217

Comment: @Bodo Thanks a lot, so to use the remaining space of the disk `/dev/sdb` I would need to create additional 3 partitions each with 2TB space because of msdos (in case I don't want to convert the partition table)?

Comment: I think with 512 bytes sector size there is a limit of about 4TB for the disk size, so you might not be able to use the whole disk with a msdos type partition table.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all background information there. Please explain why you can't (or don't want to) switch to a GPT partition table. Maybe someone else knows more details about using the maximum size with a msdos partition. I would switch to GPT in your case.